# Why doesn't Kotlin perform automatic type-casting?

Tags: casting, kotlin

```
var a : Double
a = Math.sin(10) // error: the integer literal does not conform to the expected type Double
a = Math.sin(10.0) //This compiles successfully
println(a)
```

Why doesn't kotlin perform implicit type conversion and force us to pass the exact type of data?

```
fun sin(value: Double): Double // at kotlin documentation
```

Comment: Good question, I would also like to know the reason for this. I know that an implicit cast would be performed if you do a type check but in this instance it's perfectly safe to cast implicitly without type checking, java does this so they should also be able to do it.

Comment: @Neil No you cannot just cast numeric types, that will cause errors like "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double" ... nor is that correct for how it should be done in Kotlin.

Comment: @JaysonMinard thanks for your response. I was thinking in terms of primitive types that aren't nullable in java, not boxed types. I wasn't considering nullable objects, which was pretty stupid, because Kotlin is all objects. Still new to the language, loving it though.

Answer (score 8):

We all know that Kotlin has both non-nullable `Int` and nullable `Int?`.

When we use `Int?` this happens: Kotlin actually 'boxes' JVM primitives when Kotlin needs a nullable reference since it's aimed at eliminating the danger of null references from code.

Now look at this: (assuming this is a compilable code)

```
val a: Int? = 1
val b: Long? = a
```

Kotlin doesn't perform implicit type conversion because of this thing happens. If Kotlin did implicit type conversions, `b` should be `1`. but since `a` is a boxed `Int` and `b` is a boxed `Long`, **`a == b` yields `false`** and falls into contradiction, since its `==` operator checks for `equals()` and `Long`'s `equals()` checks other part to be `Long` as well.

Check the documentation:

- [Explicit Conversions in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#explicit-conversions)
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/equality.html

Comment: This is the correct answer. Other answers point out that automatic casting may sometimes result in loss of precision, but that's not the fundamental reason why it wasn't done in Kotlin. This is THE reason, as explained in the docs

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin does not allow implicit conversions of numeric types.  There is a misconception that implicit conversions are "*no harm, no foul*" ... which is wrong.

The process in Java for implicit conversions is more complicated than you think, [read the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html) to see what all is entailed.  And then you can try to analyze all of the cases that can go wrong.

Kotlin, does not want the compiler to guess as to your intention, so it makes everything in the language explicit, including numeric type conversions.  As explained in the Kotlin docs for [Explicit Conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/numbers.html#explicit-number-conversions) it says clearly:

> Due to different representations, smaller types are not subtypes of bigger ones.
> [...]
> As a consequence, smaller types are NOT implicitly converted to bigger types.
> [...]
> We can use explicit conversions to widen numbers.

And the documentation shows one such sample of where things can go wrong, but there are many others.

Nor can you just cast one numeric type to another, as mentioned here in incorrect comments and answers.  That will only result in a nice runtime error.  Instead look at the numeric conversion functions such as `toInt()` and `toDouble()` found on the numeric types, such as on the [Number class](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/index.html#functions).

Explicitness is part of the Kotlin personality, and it is not planned to change.

Answer (score 2):

Automatic type casting for numeric types can lead to losing precision. Just consider following java code:

```
double hoursSinceUnixEra = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000/60/60;
```

The intention was not to cut the result to full hours, although it compiles without any warning in Java.

```
val hoursSinceUnixEra = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000/60/60;
someObject.doubleValue = hoursSinceUnixEra
```

Above Kotlin code won't compile due to unexplicit casting.

Issue of this type can be very hard to find and fix and it's the reason behind this decision.
You can still explicitly convert type:

```
val value = 3
Math.sin(value.toDouble())
```

Comment: This answer has a bad suggestion at the end.  That cast is going to generate a compiler warning "cast will never succeed" .  And then, it will blow up with a runtime error "java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double" ... and makes no sense as it is almost longer than `toDouble()`

Comment: @JaysonMinard You're right - I've fixed the Kotlin code.