# In kotlin while overloading functions I keep getting a "Type mismatch" on some very basic code

Tags: kotlin, geometry, overloading

on the bottom function I keep getting
`Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Double was expected` I have done similar before by declaring the output as a double with an Int input. This is however my first time working with "math.PI" and "math.pow"

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val   radius = 13;
    println(getArea(radius));
}
fun getArea(radius: Double): Double{
    val area = Math.pow(radius, radius) * Math.PI;
    return area;
}

fun getArea(radius: Int): Double{
    val area = Math.pow(radius, radius) * Math.PI;
    return area;
}
```

Comment: _val area = Math.pow(radius.toDouble(), radius.toDouble()) * Math.PI;_ will do.

Comment: Instead of re-defining the function body you might as well re-use the other function, such as `fun getArea(radius: Int): Double = getArea(radius.toDouble())`

Comment: What is Math.pow(radius, radius)?  Wrong.  That means r^r.  You want r^2 = radius*radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to summarize the different contributed comments to formulate a hopefully complete answer to your question.

**Incompatible type**

First and foremost to your actual problem. the `Math.pow` function has the following signature, as can be seen in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)):

```java
public static double pow(double a, double b)
```

You however attempt to invoke this function by passing two `Int`egers into it, thus you receive the compilation error:

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Double was expected

In contrast to some other languages one might have worked with before, Kotlin does not perform automatic type-casting for numeric types, you can find more information why that is in this [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44081233/3160089).

**Mistake in math formula**

Assuming you aim to calculate the area of a circle, you have a mistake in your formula.

It should be `A = r^2 * π` but you got `A = r^r * π`.

**Code reuse**

If you want to provide the same function for differently typed parameters it might provide useful to implement it once and make use of the single implementation in the overloaded versions.

Keeping close to your original code, this might look something like the following.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val radius = 13;
    println(getArea(radius));
}

fun getArea(radius: Double): Double {
    val area = Math.pow(radius, 2) * Math.PI;
    return area;
}

fun getArea(radius: Int): Double {
    return getArea(radius.toDouble())
}
```

**Syntax improvements**

Kotlin is a very expressive language, which allows you to simplify your code as follows. You do not need semicolons in Kotlin. For simple functions that are a single expression, Kotlin provides a [neat shortened syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#single-expression-functions). The standard library of Kotlin also provides basic math functionality such as a [pow function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/pow.html) and a [π constant](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/-p-i.html). So you don't need to rely on the Java/JVM specific functions, e.g. from `Math`.

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.PI
import kotlin.math.pow

fun getArea(radius: Double): Double = 
    radius.pow(2) * PI

fun getArea(radius: Int): Double = 
    getArea(radius.toDouble())
```

Comment: May be worth mentioning that the first issue may be surprising if you have experience with languages like Java or C that convert numbers automatically. That can be very handy, but can also lead to obscure bugs (if the conversion overflows or loses precision, or causes an unexpected overload to be used). So for safety, Kotlin requires explicit conversions (such as `.toDouble()` here).

Comment: Thanks @gidds for pointing that out. I've added a short paragraph about it to my answer.